# .NET object: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection . Client callbacks are not supported for NAV Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, microsoft-dynamics, nas, navision

I use .net variables in a codeunit to be able to connect to SQLServer. The codeunit works well when I run it manually. However, I get an error when it runs on Job Queue. I get this error: 
"Microsoft Dynamics NAV Server attempted to issue a client callback to create a .NET object: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection . Client callbacks are not supported for Microsoft Dynamics NAV Server."
The properties 'RunOnClient' are set to 'No'.
How to make these variables supported by Microsoft Dynamics NAV Server?

Comment: Please check ALL your variables carefully. The only reason for this error is RunOnClient. Nothing else.

Comment: I checked many times. All the .net variables properties 'RunOnClient' are set to 'No'.

Comment: Use debugger. It will stop when hit the variable which is client side.

Answer (score 0):

A client callback can also be caused by other 'visual' interactions, like a dialog or confirm window. If this is the case use guiallowed to check if interaction is possible

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes, I used Gui Allowed to avoid receiving job queue error emails, but its use does not resolve the job queue problem. Do you know how to check if there is a dialog or a confirm window or other visual interactions?

Comment: With 'debug next' you can try to debug the job queue and check where the issue is